# twitter bootstrap carousel issues when animating

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the bootstrap carousel as you can see on [this website][1]. I am having a hard time on why every time I go from one slide to the other it always gives that weird animation. Been debugging it for hours. I think it has to do with the css. The weird issue is that this always happens when ever I go forward, but not backwards. Oh and the issue only happens on screen resolution that is bigger than 1500px

Comment: @MarkWinterbottom the issue is that on the carousel when you hit next, it glitches.. the div height goes smaller and then it grows bigger again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you explain the reasoning why?

Comment: I am not sure why. I checked your code and noticed that inside .item there were img and .carousel-caption which both had width defined in percents. I thought that their parent .item needs to stretch to cover whole area so they would gain right widths. I am not sure if that was the reason but I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css file to include the following:

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    height: 428px;
}
```

I just tested it and it fixes the glitching.

Comment: Setting the height will break the carousel when the window is resized.